# CodedUI: Find WinTable specific column index

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

How to get column index by specifying column name?

Code:

```
WinTable UICustTable = new WinTable(UICustGrid);
int columnIndex=UICustTable.GetColumnNames("Column1");
```

Can we do somethig like this? This wont work actually. My column placement changes on different windows.

Help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   WinTable a = new WinTable();

   var desiredColumn = a.ColumnHeaders.FirstOrDefault(columnHeader => columnHeader.Name == "Column1");

   int indexOfColumn;
   if (desiredColumn!=null)
   {
       indexOfColumn = a.ColumnHeaders.IndexOf(desiredColumn);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I`m getting desiredColumn as null, i`m passing correct column name, a.ColumnHeaders is nothing. Please check your answer.

Comment: working on win forms can be tricky, especially when manipulating tables because many of the built in uitestcontrol funcitons doesn't work as expected. you'll need to come up with a work around which usually case specific